# Not sure how to grab the variables properly

Tags: jquery, variables

I am trying to make it so when a user clicks a radio it sets a variable, then clicks a second radio and makes a second variable.

Then I want to merge those two variables and load some data via ajax based on the variable that is created. To test it I made a button I could click just to test if the variable is there but it's not showing up so I am assuming I'm not doing something right.

I really appreciate your help, I am very new to this and just having a lot of trouble.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("input:radio[name=f_1]").click(function() {
      type = $(this).val();
    });

    $("input:radio[name=f_1a]").click(function() {
      prod = $(this).val();
    });

    var type, prod;
    var JobType = type + prod;
    $("#alertButton").click(function(){
      alert (JobType);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: try putting parseInt() around the set of the variables. eg. prod = parseInt($(this).val()); You are using the + so maybe js is having issues with adding two strings for some reason.

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting your code.  What do you mean by "it's not showing up"?  Does a blank alert show or does an alert show at all?

Comment: something like ... [this](http://jsfiddle.net/drinchev/rzSgy/)

Comment: When I click the button for the alert, it alerts "NaN" which I assume means it has no value.

Comment: declare the variable type and prod at the first line and try. there could be possibility that it reset value. Also, put alert inside radio button click function and check the value.

Comment: @drinchev - that is what I need, I'm not sure what that fiddle thing is, I need to look into that.

Comment: It is web app for javascript/html/css testing ... ;)

Comment: -1 I saw you asked the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254152/a-variable-is-breaking-my-code)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code :

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {

    var selected = $("input:radio:checked");

    if ( selected.length === 2 ) {
        var f = $("input[name='f']:checked").val();
        var z = $("input[name='z']:checked").val();           
        alert('we have values ['+z+f+']');
    }

});
```

​
In your code you have variable declaration outside the scope of your function, so you could not get the variables that you want.

Comment: on this, do the values of the radios have to be 2 characters long?

Comment: I'm sorry for the multiple post, I didn't realize it was the same, when I posted the other it was because when I added the variable it would mess up the structure of the page, this was that the variable wasn't acting like i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are only joined on page load (when they are empty), as they are not inside a function.

Declare your variables at the top, and put the joining of the variables inside the click function when they actually have a value, and it works just fine:

```
$(function(){
    var type="", prod="", JobType="";

    $("input:radio[name=f_1]").click(function() {
        type = $(this).val();
    });

    $("input:radio[name=f_1a]").click(function() {
        prod = $(this).val();
    });


    $("#alertButton").click(function(){
        JobType = type + prod;
        alert (JobType);
    });
});​
```

If you give your variables an initial value of nothing (""), you avoid "undefined" problems.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/EUgfK/)